# At which intervals are the new variables defined?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Considering an appropriate lineat mapping $(x,y)=T(u,v)$, I want to compute by changing the variable the integral $\iint_D e^{\frac{y-x}{y+x}}dxdy$, where $D$ os the triangle with edges the point $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We define the new variables $u=x+ y$, $v=x-y$.

When we solve for $x,y$ as a function of $u,v$ we get $$x=\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}, \ y=\frac{u}{2}-\frac{v}{2}$$

So we get the following linear mapping $$\binom{x}{y}=T\left (\binom{u}{v}\right )=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2} \\ \frac{u}{2}-\frac{v}{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\binom{u}{v}$$

At which intervals do the new variables lie?

Comment: Did you try to evaluate $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ in the points of the triangle?

Comment: Do you mean at the edges? We have the following: $$u(0,0)=0, \ u(1,0)=1, \ u(0,1)=1 \\ v(0,0)=0, \ v(1,0)=1, \ v(0,1)=-1$$ Therefore we get that $$0\leq u\leq 1 , \ \ -1\leq v\leq 1$$ right? @IEDCPHY

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that

Comment: So, we have the following: $$\iint_D e^{\frac{y-x}{y+x}}dxdy=\det \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\int_0^1\int_{-1}^1e^{-\frac{v}{u}}dvdu=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1-u\left (e^{-\frac{1}{u}}-e^{\frac{1}{u}}\right )du$$ right? How could we calculate this integral? @IEDCPHY

Comment: Or could wew simplify somehow the expression $\frac{y-x}{y+x}$ by the new variables? @IEDCPHY

Comment: Yes, the integral is right. But I looked at Wolfram, but it says the integral does not converge. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x(e%5E(-1%2Fx)-e%5E(1%2Fx))++from+x%3D0+to+1

Comment: $0\le u\le 1$, $-1\le v\le 1$ is not right. For example, $u=0$, $v=-1$ will give negative $x$, which is outside $D$.

Comment: Ahh... But how can we find then the interval of u and v? @IEDCPHY

Comment: I think the problem is that the change of variable from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ in the triangle translates into other triangle in the $uv$-plane. So the interval is $0\leq u \leq 1$ and $-u \leq v \leq u$.

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! :-) @IEDCPHY

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/331236/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141532/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the bounds for $u$, $v$ you should map the area $D$ to the new coordinate system $uv$. Since the mapping is linear, the lines map to lines, so it is enough to map just the vertices of the triangle and to get the new triangle as $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

Comment: Ah ok! So we get the following: $$\iint_D e^{\frac{y-x}{y+x}}dxdy=\det \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\int_0^1\int_{-u}^ue^{-\frac{v}{u}}dvdu=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1-u\left (e^{-1}-e\right )du \\ =\frac{e^{-1}-e}{2}\int_0^1udu=\frac{e^{-1}-e}{4}$$ right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it seems right.

Comment: Can a double integral be negativ (as in this case) although it is the volume?

Comment: @MaryStar You are right, it must be positive. You should take the **absolute value** of the determinant in the change of variables.

Comment: Why should we do that? Is the general formula with the absolute value?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, the volume scaling is positive, i.e. the [absolute value of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you so much!! :-)